# How to set password for snowchange

Tags: python, environment-variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to run snowchange as explained in the [README](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/snowchange).

```
python snowchange/cli.py -a SNOWFLAKE_ACCOUNT -u SNOWFLAKE_USER -r SNOWFLAKE_ROLE -w SNOWFLAKE_WAREHOUSE -d SNOWFLAKE_DATABASE --create-change-history-table
```

However I do not understand how to set the environment variable for the password.

Tried: Setting the password in an interactive python. It doesn't work as the variable is set only for the current process and when going out of the python command line to execute the command, I don't have access anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass by Powershell command as below

```
setx SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD passwordvalue
```

But make sure when you have a $ sign in password, it can't work from client, you have to add it from GUI User-specific windows envs.

Ref: https://rajivgupta780184.medium.com/database-change-management-tool-schemachange-with-snowflake-overview-b62dec744e0a